# ffmpeg cpu stuck at 99%

Tags: ffmpeg

I get this  sometimes when using ffmpeg

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:559x1425 fmt:yuvj420p to size:429x323 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:429x323 fmt:yuvj420p to size:800x600 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:800x600 fmt:yuvj420p to size:260x259 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:260x259 fmt:yuvj420p to size:240x160 fmt:yuvj444p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:240x160 fmt:yuvj444p to size:648x783 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:648x783 fmt:yuvj420p to size:340x254 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:340x254 fmt:yuvj420p to size:260x259 fmt:yuvj420p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:260x259 fmt:yuvj420p to size:500x438 fmt:yuvj444p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:500x438 fmt:yuvj444p to size:391x512 fmt:yuvj444p
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:391x512 fmt:yuvj444p to size:300x225 fmt:yuvj422p
```

ffmpeg freeze
htop say the processor is at 99%

I look if its the jpg that is the problem , it is not 
and when i do again the ffmpeg command ffmpeg `ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r 1/5 -i out-%02d.jpg out.avi`
it work.

It seem that in my loop sometimes ffmpeg freeze and make processor at 99% . Any ideas

Thank you

I use last version http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

Comment: Please provide the full uncut command line output.

Comment: that's the full command line output , it freeze after . I get 
this too sometimes : 
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.52 bitrate=N/A
video:973kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.002209%
*** glibc detected *** ffmpeg: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0932d9a0 ***
*** glibc detected *** ffmpeg: malloc(): memory corruption: 0xb498a738 ***

Comment: Please edit your question with the code rather than posting it in a comment. Thank you!